# Team Services Azure App Service Deploy failure - Virtual Application characters?

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, msbuild-task

I have 2 Azure App Service Deploy steps in a Team Services build, they have the same Subscription details. The only difference is that they target different virtual applications - the one that fails contains an é character, could that be the cause? Here the step output:

2017-01-17T16:04:22.8323742Z 8570d8e4-b732-4c45-87c5-619fe9343427 exists true

2017-01-17T16:04:24.5778681Z Got connection details for Azure App Service:'foo'

2017-01-17T16:04:24.6088690Z Running command: "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:getParameters -source:package="C:\a\1\a\Foo.zip" > "C:\a\1\s\parameter.xml"

2017-01-17T16:04:25.4027522Z Running command: @echo off

2017-01-17T16:04:25.4027522Z "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe"  -verb:sync -source:package="C:\a\1\a\Foo.zip" -dest:auto,ComputerName='https://foo.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=foo',UserName='********',Password='********',AuthType='Basic' -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='foo/bar-é' -userAgent:VSTS_foo_build_154_744 2>error.txt

2017-01-17T16:04:25.4027522Z if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%

2017-01-17T16:04:25.4067519Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C C:\a\1\s\msDeployCommand.bat

2017-01-17T16:04:25.4157662Z 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

2017-01-17T16:04:25.4167533Z operable program or batch file.

2017-01-17T16:04:25.4207534Z ##[error]Failed to deploy App Service.

2017-01-17T16:04:29.2496923Z ##[error]Error: Error: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe failed with return code: 9009

2017-01-17T16:04:29.2576899Z ##[section]Finishing: Azure App Service Deploy: foo-dev-global

It's almost as if the Powershell command itself is broken, I'm guessing by the special character.

Comment: Can you run the build with variable "system.debug" set to "true" and share the logs?

Answer (score 1):

It maybe not the special character causes that issue.  I try to deploy the virtual Application with the special characters  é , following is my detail steps.  Hope it is useful. We also can get  moreinfo about WebDeploy error code please refer to [document](https://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED).

1.Create a new build definition for the project

[image]

2.Select build solution corresponding VS version.

[image]

3. Before config Azure App Service Deployment, we need to create a WebApp in the Azure portal and the edit the appsetting to add the 
   Virtual applications info

[image]

4. Config the Azure App Service Deployment with service name and Virtual application created in the step3

[image]

5.New Queue build for the build definition

[image]

6. Then we can check that it deployed successfully from deployment log or from kudu.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, perhaps there's a different issue as I have almost the same build settings. I have the following msbuild arguments: /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=AzureDevFrench /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:StyleCopEnabled=false /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False. Also, in my Azure Portal the directory is site\marchés-des-particuliers and not site\wwwrot\marchés-des-particuliers as per your example.

Comment: I also did not have the forward slash in front of the virtual application name in the deploy step but adding it did not work.

Comment: The error states C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command when attempting to run C:\Program Files\IIS\...\msdeploy.exe - that seems to indicate a syntax error? As stated, I have an identical Azure App Services deploy step in this build that deploys to another virtual application in the same App Service without issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is now working as expected, without me making any changes. Having informed MS of the issue, I can only conclude they've released a fix to the build task.